# SMTP connect() failed phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```php
<?php

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemail';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypass';                           // SMTP password
//  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'myemail@yahoo.com';
$mail->FromName = 'abc';
$mail->addAddress('abc@abc.com');               // Name is optional


//$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
//  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if (! $mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I have tried gmail also but it keeps giving me error SMTP connect() failed.

here is the error

```
    2015-05-16 07:28:09    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2015-05-16 07:28:09    CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2015-05-16 07:28:10    CLIENT -> SERVER: bWF0ZWVuX3VsX2hhcUB5YWhvby5jb20=
2015-05-16 07:28:10    CLIENT -> SERVER: c2hhaGlkYWZyaWRpMW1hcmNoMTk5MQ==
2015-05-16 07:28:11    SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 501 Syntax error in arguments
2015-05-16 07:28:11    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2015-05-16 07:28:11    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-05-16 07:28:11    SMTP connect() failed.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Message could not be sent.

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: There are several other questions similar to this one here. Did you check them?

Comment: @Masiorama Yes seen them all nothing worked

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq Change your gmail password. You have just made your account details public.

Comment: @Phylogenesis i did not mention any thing where did you find it ?

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq They're Base64 encoded in the two lines after the `AUTH LOGIN` line.

Comment: You should really read what the troubleshooting guide says. Set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what the server says.

Comment: @Synchro it Solved my problem post it as answer so i will accept it

Comment: Hope this might help you [PHPMailer Connection Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614035/smtp-connection-failed/46626768#46626768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read what [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) says - that's why the link to it is included in the error output. Set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what the server says and it will probably tell you what's wrong.