# Getting trouble with SMTP connect with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send SMTP secured mail with attachment using PHPMailer.

I made this function with PHPMailer library

```
public function sendCsv($subject,$body,$path,$mail_to,$from_name,$from_mail,$replyto){

    require getcwd() .'/lib/PHPMailerAutoload.php';             

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;      // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();              // Set mailer to use SMTP

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
    $mail->Username = 'tester@mydomain.com';                
    $mail->Password = '**************';                          
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
    $mail->Port = 465;                            

    $mail->setFrom($from_mail, $from_name);
    $mail->addAddress($mail_to);  
    $mail->addReplyTo($replyto, 'no reply');

    $mail->addAttachment($path);        
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body    = $body;
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        echo  $error;
        } else {
            $sucess = 'Mail sent!';
            echo  $sucess;
            }
    }
```

Now if I comment the line $mail->isSMTP(); it's working fine . but I think it's not SMTP secured. Else I am getting this message: "Mail error: SMTP connect() failed.  "

I searched for this problem but didn't get the proper answer to what I am looking for. Please help me.

I am working in a dev server with HTACCESS protection

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer and you need to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Also, search before posting, there are many duplicates of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP connect() failed phpmailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476024/smtp-connect-failed-phpmailer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the details to fix the issue here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting .

I have just Turned on less secure apps https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps from my gmail account.

**This takes few minutes or an hour to active.**

My current code :

```
public function sendCsv($subject,$body,$path,$mail_to,$from_name,$from_mail,$replyto){
            require getcwd() .'/lib/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; 
            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->isSMTP();   
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
            $mail->Port = 587;  

            $mail->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com';                
            $mail->Password = 'mypass';                                     


            $mail->setFrom($from_mail, $from_name);
            $mail->addAddress($mail_to);  
            $mail->addReplyTo($replyto, 'no reply');

            $mail->addAttachment($path);        
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  

            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $mail->Body    = $body;
            //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
                echo $error;
            } else {
                $sucess = 'Mail sent!';
                echo  $sucess;
            }
        }
```

Else you have to Setup a app from console.developers.google.com

Follow this guide : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2