# SMTP connection failed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mailer

I'm facing this issue from last three days, before this script worked perfectly. Now getting error:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2017-10-06 21:05:34  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   ahsanazhar12@gmail.com

Here is my script:

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                  // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                       // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';        // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';             // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;   
$mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

I think Gmail may have changed settings for sending emails using SMTP, or something like that.

Comment: Here's a wild idea - try following the link in the error message, which tells you all about this and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i'm able to send emails from localhost. Here is my code.

To install:

1. Download PHPMailer
2. Add it to your project (i put it on root)
3. Add Autoload class to  your Script.
4. Rest of code is below

   ```
           require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
           $mail = new PHPMailer;
           $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
               'ssl' => array(
                   'verify_peer' => false,
                   'verify_peer_name' => false,
                   'allow_self_signed' => true
               )
           );
           //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
           $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
           $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
           $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
           $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
           $mail->Password = 'securepass';                           // SMTP password
           $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
           $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
           //Recipients
           $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', "Mailer");
           $mail->addAddress("example@gmail.com","receiver Name");  
           $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
           $mail->Subject = "Subject";
           $mail->Body    = "Body";
           $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
              if( $mail->send()){
               return array("msg"=>msg("success","Email has been sent.<br>"));
               } else {
                   return array("msg"=>msg("error","Email can't send.Try Again<br>"));
               }
   ```